# How to transfer a string from WIX installer to a VB script?

Tags: vb.net, wix

I have build an installer to install machine software. However the user is required to fill in one value (the machine ID) this because it needs to replace a value already present in the .INI file. The code to replace the value is no problem since I already got it working.

However I dont know how to get the value (for example: DE123654) from the WIX installer in the script that is being executed to replace the value using a WIX custom action. I created a Custom form for asking the value and the code i use to get the value is as following:

```
<Control Id="InputField" Type="Edit" X="20" Y="100" Width="140" Height="18" Property="MachineIdNumber" Text="{80}"/>
```

I found this code on this website, however I don't know how to get the value from here into my script or how I can make the script look up the value that has been entered. any suggestion on how I can achieve this?

I ask for the MachineID at the beginning of the installation process, so the value is known before the actual installation process starts.
the script is embedded in the installer and is being executed at the end of the installation process since the file that needs to be altered is already at the correct location on the targer system.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you call a mini executable, from within the installer, with the machine name as a command line parameter and then manage it from there?

Comment: I am afraid I don't fully understand what you are saying. my knowledge with this sort of things is limited. the script I invoke is an executable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom action to set the properties you want to pass and the `Property` value must be the same as the `Id` of the custom action calling the script, this way:

```
<Product ...>
    <CustomAction
        Id="SetProperties"
        Property="ScriptCA"
        HideTarget="yes"
        Value="[MachineIdNumber];[OtherProperty]"
        />

    <CustomAction
        Id="ScriptCA"
        BinaryKey="CustomActionsLib"
        DllEntry="ScriptMethod"
        Execute="deferred"
        Impersonate="no"
        Return="check"
        />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="SetProperties" Before="ScriptCA" />
        <Custom Action="ScriptCA" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

 </Product>
```

Comment: thanks for the information. however I still have a few questions, should I create a new script just to change the value or can I use the script I am already using? ( i think a new script is the way to go) I understand that the custom action offers the Value to the script bud how do I incorporate it in my script so it will take the Value and uses it? of course I am also trying to find it out myself bud i just don't yet know what exactly to look for. bud I will do my best.

Comment: You need to include your script's code (the relevant part of it). It is difficult to answer your question in a more direct way without it.

Comment: I do almost have it working. however the value isn't used correctly since the text that is replacing the old text is incorrect. I use the following code in the VB script to get the value: <code>Dim MachineID As String = Command() <code> however this places some kind of link to a temp file instead of the value I would like to have. I tried a couple of things bud none of them worked. what am i doing wrong?